# Adding PHP in HTML tag

Tags: php, html, tags

Can I use PHP code (for dynamic content) in HTML `a` tag?

I've a code like this:

```
<ul>
              <li>
            <a href="#" class="offset" title="The sun escaping the horizon">
                <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" class="imagequery">
            </a>
        </li>
          </ul>
```

I need to place my PHP code as title in a tag.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like this:  <a href="#" class="offset" title="<?php echo 'title generated from PHP code'; ?>">

Comment: Why don't you try something and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

```
    //yes it is possible 
    <ul>
    <li>
    <?php $title="The sun escaping the horizon";?>
    <a href="#" class="offset" title="<?php echo $title;?>">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" class="imagequery">
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $title = "My Test Title"; ?>
<ul>
          <li>
        <a href="#" class="offset" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" class="imagequery">
        </a>
    </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Title is dynamic it's come from published posts is not static note.